# VR 360 images on my site

Tags: html, 360-degrees

im working on a new project and im trying to get the 360 image i took with my 360 camera to display in my site so far i have:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="700px" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" src="index.html?image=IMG_0222.jpg&is_stereo=false"></iframe>
```

but i keep getting an error message saying:

The requested URL /test/index.html was not found on this server.

the file were im trying to is call test.html, on that folder i only have the IMG_0222.jpg and the test.html files....

i believe my problem is not having that index.html, if that is the answer what should that index.html file have on it?

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Can you show me the folder structure? @JAC

Comment: mysite.com/test/test.html mysite/test/IMG_0222.jpg i also just added index.html. on it i add <img src="IMG_0222.jpg" width="100%"> and it does show my image but flat no 360 functions....

Comment: i have use this code:

Comment: <iframe width="100%" height="300px" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/index.html?image=//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/coral.jpg&is_stereo=true"></iframe>

Comment: this one works fine....but i want to use the images i host not that image that shows from there....

Comment: thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay So url of your hosted image? @JAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking everywhere for the answer i found this blog

http://blog.mastermaps.com/2014/01/photo-spheres-with-threejs.html

it gave me the right answers to wrap my 360 image in a sphere so it could be display as a 360 image using Threejs once i did that i was able to load the image with full 360 rotation action into the index.html file and finally displaying in my test.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add the right path of the VR image/video file.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="700px" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" src=" **full_url_path_till_vr_file** &is_stereo=false"></iframe>
```

For more details you can visit following link:

[Embedding VR View](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview)

Comment: this is the answer using your answer   The requested URL /test/IMG_0222jpg&is_stereo=false was not found on this server.

Comment: when i wrote here but i did double check it was not that....still does not work...

Comment: Use full url including hostname! @JAC